# Which regulation does this sentence about IPv6 refer to?

Tags: ipv6

> "For this, you need to obtain an IPv6 address from your ISP. 
>   Technically this could be a `/128` prefix (exactly one IPv6
>   address), but according to regulation it needs to be at least a `/64` prefix."

from the [OpenWRT Wiki](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/ipv6?s%5B#native.ipv6.access)

To what regulations are they referring? 
(So that if I need to defend myself when the time comes, I'll be able to point to something)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It likely refers to the [RFC 6177](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6177).

```
  A key principle for address management is that end sites always be
  able to obtain a reasonable amount of address space for their
  actual and planned usage, and over time ranges specified in years
  rather than just months.  In practice, that means at least one
  /64, and in most cases significantly more.  One particular
  situation that must be avoided is having an end site feel
  compelled to use IPv6-to-IPv6 Network Address Translation or other
  burdensome address conservation techniques because it could not
  get sufficient address space.
```

Comment: I edit the OpenWRT wiki from time to time, and I updated it to point to this RFC.